# update_post_meta not work only when save data, not for update

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some trouble with regular wordpress functions in class methods
I save post meta like this and Its works fine:

```
public function saveMetadata( $postname ) {
    $post_id     = $_POST[ 'post_ID' ];
    $post_holder = $_POST[ $postname ];

    update_post_meta( $post_id, $postname, $post_holder );

}
```

But when i try update meta use same method, it doesnt work! why?

Thats i invoke this

```
//creation and run object
add_action( 'save_post', $quality->saveMetadata( 'project_quality' ) );
```

Comment: Your code does not have any error checking nor did you reveal what you've tried so far to find out more. The code as you have posted it *must not* update any post meta. It could, but it must not. So you have to show why you think it must.

Comment: in var_dump all values isset, but update_post_meta doesnt save it, his works only for first save, then i cannot update meta

Comment: It's important you use the correct post_ID, see as well http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta

Comment: post id is correct and thats why data saved at first record

Comment: No post ID is not correct, that is shown because you can't update.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/4DmBEDNPFKY4rP
http://joxi.ru/LVm6b7QoHN80mZ

Comment: http://joxi.ru/LVm6b7QoHN80mZ

Comment: http://joxi.ru/LQ2Kx7pQTkEWAj

Comment: That's a GET parameter with (even) a *different* name.

Comment: Ofc it get param. but when i send form i handle equal post data via $_POST[ 'post_ID' ]

Comment: If you're sure that post_ID is correct, ensure that `$post_holder` is not NULL.

Comment: post_id meta_value and meta_key http://joxi.ru/K823jpkoHylGmO

Comment: are you using a cache on post meta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I solved this by using anonimous functions inside action, and send variable $post_id inside it.
It seems, wordpress expext id exacly from this var, strange but it works. Here the code:

```
public function saveMetadata() {

    add_action('save_post', function($post_id){
        if(isset($_POST[$this->id])) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $this->id, $_POST[ $this->id] );
        }
    });
}
```

Note: without any validation.

And invoke it, ofc:

```
//object creation and run
$someObject->saveMetadata();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, I tried to update an order's post meta in my class function with WP AJAX, but get_post_meta() worked, update not, so I solved it with deletetion of actual meta and add again new data, short example:

```
public function order_decision_ajax_callback()
{
    $current_custom_postmeta = get_post_meta($orderID, 'custompostmeta', true);
    if($current_custom_postmeta)
    {
        delete_post_meta($orderID, 'custompostmeta');
    }
    add_post_meta($orderID, 'custompostmeta', $newmeta);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding priority

`add_action( 'save_post', $quality->saveMetadata( 'project_quality' ), 999 );`

also, try checking the database table wp_postmeta to verify if there's project_quality

I've having the same issue with update_post_meta functions but its because of Yoast SEO Field priority which I can't figure out

This might help

[update_post_meta for Wordpress Yoast SEO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642385/update-post-meta-for-wordpress-yoast-seot)

Comment: very strange. if i do var_dump($_post); exit; - i got aalll post, but if without exit - post is empty, totally