# update_post_meta for Wordpress Yoast SEO

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having trouble with Yoast Worpdress SEO to automatically Update the Title, Keywords and description,

I have tried several ways with no success,

First test I've done is something like this, adding directly in fucntions.php

`update_post_meta('80', '_yoast_wpseo_title', 'Test SEO Title' );`

It works fine, however when I try a method like this, it won't simply work

```
function save_seo_meta_data($post_id) {
    global $post;
    $data = new MovieData;

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) 
        return $post_id; 
    if ('movie_post' == $_POST['post_type']) { 
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) 
            return $post_id; 
        } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) { 
            return $post_id; 
    }
    #wpseo_set_value('title', $data->seotitle, $post_id);
    #WPSEO_Meta::set_value('title', $data->seotitle,$post_id);
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', $data->title );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_seo_meta_data',9999999);
```

all of these three works using the above code when I change the meta key to different value

```
wpseo_set_value('title', $data->seotitle, $post_id);
WPSEO_Meta::set_value('title', $data->seotitle,$post_id);
update_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', $data->title );
```

I check the wp_postmeta value and can see all the value if I set different keys, but not when I point to yoast seo meta keys,

I've been also looking into its class and functions from here,

:https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/ba4b1ad63f64d9658a2cc8de22b4391459423516/inc/class-wpseo-meta.php

:https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/ba4b1ad63f64d9658a2cc8de22b4391459423516/inc/wpseo-functions.php

But still no success

Any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the `wpseo_saved_postdata` hook:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse26642385_save_post', 1, 1 );
function wpse26642385_save_post( $post_id )
{
    // check stuff

    // $data = ...

    add_action( 'wpseo_saved_postdata', function() use ( $post_id ) {
        if( function_exists( 'wpseo_set_value' ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', $data->title );
        }
    }, 999 );
}
```

Comment: I used similar code for a client project. I remember it took me a while to figure it out :) Cheers!